# Javascript - div inside div problem

Tags: javascript, html

I need the `hideall()` function to execute when the mouse moves out of `id1`. With the code below, it calls `hideall()` correctly but it calls it again when the mouse moves out of `id2`.

```
<div id="id1" onmouseout="hideall();" style="border:1px solid red;">
          <div id="id2">This is inside id1 div</div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrfsM.png

Comment: The mouseout event I think only happens when moves the mouse from somewhere to somewhere. If I understand correctly, the hideall() in your code should be called when the mouse is in id1, and moves outside of id1. Are you claiming that hideall() is also incorrectly triggered when the mouse moves from id1(but not id2)->id2? Or when it moves from id2->outside_id2?

Comment: When I move mouse from id1>id2 and from id1>body then call hideall() function. I need that hideall() function is call just if id1>body and NOT id1>id2

Comment: I've seen a problem very much like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gsv7n/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proprietary event in Internet Explorer called mouse leave that I believe is exactly what you are looking for. Unfortunately, this will not work in all browsers. I recommend you use a javascript library like jQuery. It has the event built in. See http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ for details. So what you would probably be looking for is something like this:

```
<div id="id1" style="border:1px solid red;">
      <div id="id2">This is inside id1 div</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id1').mouseleave(function() {
        hideAll();
        // Or whatever else you want to do when the mouse leaves the element.
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting another answer I had [previously](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gsv7n/1/):

```
<div id="id1" onmouseout="showTarget('id1',0);" onmouseover="showTarget('id1',1);" style="border:1px solid red; width: 150px; height: 100px">
 <div id="id2" onmouseover="showTarget('id1',1);" onmouseout="showTarget('id1',1);" style="background-color: red; color: white; width: 100px; height: 75px;">This is inside id1 div</div>
</div>

function showTarget(target, state) {
    switch (state) {
        case 1:
            state = 'block';
        break;
        default:
            state = 'none';
    }
    console.log(state);
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = state;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMpkX/